# How does Spring call these @RequestMappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The [source code for Spring OAuth2's AuthorizationEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/AuthorizationEndpoint.java) contains two redundant `@RequestMapping` annotations for the same `/oauth/authorize` endpoint.  One of them specifies the `POST` method, while the other does not specify a method.

How are the two `@RequestMapping` annotations interpreted?  Does the one that specifies `POST` exclusively handle all `POST /oauth/authorize` requests, and does the one that does not specify a method exclusively handle any `non-POST` requests to `/oauth/authorize`?  Or do both methods overlap, with both methods being called for certain requests?

This is probably a Spring MVC question, though the source code on GitHub uses Spring MVC to define what is Spring OAuth2.

Though the complete source code is available on GitHub at the link that the top of this OP, the headers for the two relevant methods are summarized here as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/authorize")
public ModelAndView authorize(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters,
        SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {

  //other stuff
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/authorize", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = OAuth2Utils.USER_OAUTH_APPROVAL)
public View approveOrDeny(@RequestParam Map<String, String> approvalParameters, Map<String, ?> model,
        SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {

  //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is already explained [in the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--): *if* you provide the values for the `method` field, they'll be used to *narrow down* the mapping. In other words: Spring MVC will use these hints to find the most precise match for each request.

It's also easy to build a simple proof-of-concept application that demonstrates it in practice:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@ResponseBody
public String hello() {
  return "hello, default";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String helloGet() {
  return "hello, GET";
}
```

Hitting `/foo` with a GET request, for instance using Postman, will return "hello, GET". All other supported HTTP methods (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) will result in "hello, default".

Comment: I am marking this a +1 because you gave a good answer.  Thank you.  But I am not marking this as accepted because you gave -1 yesterday to both of the other answers.  I see that someone else gave them -1 again today, because I gave them both +1 yesterday to counteract your down vote.  Those 2 users took time to do research trying to shed light on the question.  If your answer is better, then your answer can stand on its own merits without your needing to downvote others.

Comment: I always downvote answers that provide factually incorrect information, *especially* when I see somebody already upvoted them before.

Answer (score -1):

The default method used by Spring request mapping is **GET**, so if you specify a request mapping with only `@RequestMapping` annotation, Spring will route all GET requests for the value of the annotation to this method.

To use any other method you basically need to say the method in the annotation. like `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST`)

So for your example the first method will only handle the GET requests, while the other will handle the POST requests exclusively.

Usually GET in OAuth is used for normal interpretations, while the POST is used to authenticate un-authenticated users using the param passed to the method, which in this case is `OAuth2Utils.USER_OAUTH_APPROVAL`.

Comment: This is not correct: GET is not the default for `@RequestMapping`. As per [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) the `method` field _narrows the primary mapping_ to the specified methods.

Answer (score -1):

> How are the two @RequestMapping annotations interpreted?

First of, from http://javatechig.com/java/spring/how-spring-controller-request-mapping-works-in-spring-mvc the default is interpreted as a `GET`. This is the first distinction. Second the paramaters of both methods are slightly different where method 1 requests a `Map<String, String>` and the other method `Map<String, ?>`. So even if both methods were `GET`, it would still make the distinction on parameter level.

> Does the one that specifies POST exclusively handle all POST
>   /oauth/authorize requests, and does the one that does not specify a
>   method exclusively handle any non-POST requests to /oauth/authorize?
>   Or do both methods overlap, with both methods being called for certain
>   requests?

The `POST` exclusively handles post and nothing else. The other method only handles `GET` requests. They **never** overlap. As is java's law and `Spring` is still bound by the rules of the java overlords =)

Comment: This is not correct: GET is not the default for `@RequestMapping`. As per [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) the method field _narrows the primary mapping_ to the specified methods. Note that this was also pointed out in a comment under the article you linked - this is why it's better to stay away from sources of second-hand knowledge with no references/citations.