# How does Spring mvc know what to do if the @RequestMapping("/someAction") is not defined in the form action property

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a form defined without an action. The attributes of the fields are associated with the model. My question is - How does Spring know what the mapping is without the action defined. I'm sure its just Spring magic but want to know the details behind it.

JSP Code:

```
         <form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="user">
         </form:form>
```

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bank-admin-actions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: your question is not  clear , you are making a POST request from your form where as your @RequestMapping accepts GET?

Comment: Sorry I need to clarify. What I am describing is in my controller i have two methods one for GET and One for Post that have the same mapping name. In an initial jsp I have an anchor that explicitly defines the controller mapping. e.g <a href="/client-admin-actions">Client Admin</a> to the get method in the controller, but in the jsp file for the form there is not an explicit property for the action as there is no action defined in the form. Just a modelAttribute. Im wondering how Spring knows which method to call without explicitly defining it within the form.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring MVC @RequestMapping annotation is capable of handling HTTP request methods, such as GET, PUT, POST and DELETE. It is explained in this documentation
[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) .

```
@RequestMapping("/api1")
@ResponseBody
public String abc() {
return "example1";
}



@RequestMapping(value="/ap1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String abc2() {
return "example2";
}
```

Now, here if you do a GET request suppose "http://localhost/ap1" using any tool(Postman for example) the response will be "example2".
All other supported HTTP methods (POST, PUT, DELETE) will result in example 1
you can refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264178/7820277) , i just **rephrased** this answer.